# Pulling in post category and children within category

Tags: posts, categories, loop

I want to pull in the 5 most recent posts in all of the child categories within one parent category. Below is the code I have so far, but I cant seem to pull in all of the child categories.

```
<ul class = "insidelinks">
        <?php
      $args = array( 'category_name' => 'news', 'numberposts' => '5' );
      $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
      foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){
        echo '
        <li>
            <a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '">' .   $recent["post_title"].'</a>
        </li> ';
      }
      wp_reset_query();
    ?>
    </ul>
```

How can I pull in the 5 most recent posts for all of the categories within a parent?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you want the 5 most recent *globally* or 5 from each of the child category?

Comment: @bynicolas 5 of the most recent globally

Comment: I just created a category named **parent-cat** and also a child of this category named **child-cat**. I copied your code and just changed the **category_name** parameter.  
On the frontend I now see 2 posts from my **parent-cat** and 3 post of my **child-cat**.  
So it seems your code works. Or Iam not fully understanding the problem ;)

Comment: then like @LWS-Mo said, it should work. So what makes you think it's not?